# Updating a 'let' statement in Swift after changing a variable

Tags: swift

I understand that Swift will read the lines sequentially, but if I change a variable after I define a statement using that variable, what function/action do I need to do for the variable to be updated?

For example:

```
var currentLocation = "Room 130"
let message = "I am currently in \(currentLocation)"
currentLocation = "Room 129"
```

How do I get the message to read "I am currently in Room 129" after changing the `var` declaration?

Comment: There are several ways to do this like a computed property or an property observer, read more in the [Properties chapter](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/properties) in the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use a getter like this:

```
var currentLocation = "Room 130"
var message: String {
    return "I am currently in \(currentLocation)"
}
currentLocation = "Room 129"

print(message)
```

To update a `let` statement as suggested in the title is not possible. `let` is for constants that do not change.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a `let` is that the result is a constant. Once it is set it cannot be changed, by design.

As others have said, you could make it a computed property, but then it would not be a `let` constant.